# Mutually exclusive input fields with JSF and PrimeFaces

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces application where I would like to make two input text fields mutually exclusive: the user should fill either field, but not both.

In the following example, the user could search contacts either by phone number or by email.

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel>Phone Number:
        <h:inputText id="phoneInput" value="#{contactSearch.phone}"
                     disabled="#{not empty contactSearch.email}">
            <p:ajax event="keyup" update="emailInput"/>
        </h:inputText>
    </h:outputLabel>
    <h:outputLabel>Email Address:
        <h:inputText id="emailInput" value="#{contactSearch.email}"
                     disabled="#{not empty contactSearch.phone}">
            <p:ajax event="keyup" update="phoneInput"/>
        </h:inputText>
    </h:outputLabel>

    <!-- Possibly other fields... -->

    <h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{contactSearch.search}"/>
</h:form>
```

Is this the proper way to do it? I am concerned about:

- Possible "deadlock" issues, where both fields end up being disabled
- The whole form being submitted and/or valdiated in the Ajax request, when I just would like to update the `disabled` state of the input field
- Missing some predefined PrimeFaces control which does all the work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not trivial in standard JSF. JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has a validator for exactly this purpose, the [`<o:validateOne>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOne).

```
<h:inputText id="email" ... />
<h:inputText id="phone" ... />
<o:validateOne components="email phone" />
```

However, in [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) perspective, you'd better redesign your form to provide a single `UISelectOne` component to select the type and a single `UIInput` field to enter the value. E.g.

```
<h:selectOneRadio ... value="#{bean.type}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="email" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="phone" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:inputText ... value="#{bean.value}" />
```

---

**Update**: as server side validation is not affordable and you'd really like to disable the the other without making much ajax traffic, your only bet is using pure JavaScript/jQuery for the job (if necessary in combination with server side validation as fallback).

Here's a generic jQuery based approach:

```
<h:inputText styleClass="onlyone" a:data-onlyone="groupName" />
<h:inputText styleClass="onlyone" a:data-onlyone="groupName" />
...
```

```
$(document).on("input", ":input.onlyone", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $others = $("[data-onlyone='" + $this.data("onlyone") + "']").not($this);
    $others.val(null).attr("disabled", !!$this.val());
});
```

The `data-onlyone` value should represent the group name, so you can have multiple of "only one" inputs throughout the document.

Comment: The actual example comes from an 'advanced search' page, where the user is not required to fill either field. `<o:validateOne>` and the related [`<o:validateOneOrNone>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOneOrNone) can only warn the user after the fact... but not prevent mistakes.